# Brownian motion - Stratonowich or Ito

Tags: soft-question, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm coming from physics background, but question seems quite general.

I think I understand the definition of both Ito and Stratonowich integral, but I still don't have an intuitive feel for the difference.

When modeling a physical process, when and why would one choose one over the other? It seems some authors claim for example that diffusion process (with diffusion coefficient dependent on location) is better modelled with Stratonowich than Ito, others use Ito and argue by *not looking into the future* property.

Why prefer one over the other (apart from chain rule convenience of Stratonowich)? Why is Stratonowich not used at all in, for example, mathematical finance?

Answer (score 1):

In case of mathematical finance martingale property of Ito integrals gives them precedence. Recall,

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^T X_t \mathrm{d}W_t \right] = \mathbb{E}[X_0]
$$
for a non-anticipating process $X_t$. From a pricing point of view this is very useful (and analogous integral in Stratonovich sense does not possess this property).

For a physicists Fokker-Plank equations for the evolution of the PDF of the studied process allow for identification of probability currents corresponding to drift and diffusion parts separately. Given $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{A} \mathrm{d}t + \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{\mathrm{d}W}$ corresponding Fokker-Planck equation reads

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p = - \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \cdot \left( (\mathbf{A} p) + \frac{1}{2}  \left(  \mathbf{B} \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} : \mathbf{B} p\right)\right)
$$

here drift current is defined uniquely in terms of $\mathbf{A}$, this is not the case for Stratonowich calculus where different square roots of diffusion matrix $\mathbf{D} = \mathbf{B} \mathbf{B}^{T}$ result in different drift terms.

For a detailed discussion of pros and cons of either approach read more in
H.C.Ottinger's *Stochastic Processes in Polymeric Fluids* (section 3.3 Stochastic Differential Equations, pg. 127-129).